# How Do I Print the values in a recursive Program in Java?

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to use a recursive program to print out a sequence that starts at one value, goes to a max, then back down to the original value.  The program can't use static or global variables, or use an array.

**Ex: `f(5,10)` prints `5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6,5`**

I think I have the concept down, at least I think I do, but I can't figure out how to print the variable from the recursive method to print the sequence.
Here is my program:

```
 public class recursive {

     public static int f(int a, int b) {
         System.out.print(a);   
         if (a == b) return a;
         else return a + f(a + 1, b) + a;

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         f(2, 5);
     }

 }
```

Do I need to Change the program to be able to print? I am fairly certain my concept is correct, I just can't print it.  Please help!!!!

Comment: Please follow naming conventions for `classes` in java. A class name MUST begin with a capital letter

Comment: This looks pretty far off the mark. I would recommend writing this in pseudo-code or even English to get something that sounds correct. Can you explain what this current one is in words?

Comment: There seems to be no point in having a return value from `f`; you don't do anything with the return value anywhere.

Comment: You need to close the function f with a `}`.

Comment: @Prateek, as you stated, it's just a **naming convention**. Classes don't _have_ to begin with a capital letter.

Comment: I tried it just there. It printed the numbers fine. i had to add the parenthesis you were missing on the else statment though. Am i missing something?

Comment: @Rohan It is better to follow such conventions from the very beginning before someone else comes in and comments on how commendable your coding style is

Comment: @Prateek, I understand. The way you phrased your comment made it sound like one would get an error if their class(es) didn't follow such convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must print inside the recursive function, just print instead of returning..

```
public static void f(int a, int b) {
    if (a == b) {
        System.out.print(a);
    }
    else {
        System.out.print(a + ",");
        f(a+1,b);
        System.out.print("," + a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I just could't make it work, not matter how many times I played around with it.  I knew it would be an easy answer, I just couldn't figure it out.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of your output as a nested series of outputs. For instance, with `f(5, 10)`, you should print a 5, then a comma, print `f(6, 10)`, then print a comma and another 5. You just need to then identify and deal with the base case (where you don't recurse) and you will be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use an array, that main(String []args) is going to be a problem ;)

What you want to do is:

```
boilerplate boilerplate void recursive(num, max) {
    System.out.print(num)

    if (number < max) {
        System.out.print(",");
        recursive(+1, max);
    }

    System.out.print(num)
}

boilerplate boilerplate main(String[] args) {
   recursive(1, 10);
}
```

Disclaimer: it's been about 15 years since I did java, so there's probably something very wrong with this -- apart from the "boilerplate" stuff ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class recursive {
    public static void f(int a, int b) {
        if (a == b) {
            System.out.print(a);
        } else {
            System.out.print(a + ",");
            f(a + 1, b);
            System.out.print("," + a);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f(2, 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: You took my code and put it in a class. -_-. Just edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I had something so similar to that and changed it about 5 times. I just couldn't make it work.  You saved my life!!!!!

Comment: The answer just the same.I also write.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void f(int a, int b) {
    if(a != b) {
        System.out.print(a + ",");
        if(a < b) {
            f(a + 1, b);
        } else {
            f(a - 1, b);
        }
        System.out.print("," + a);
    } else {
        System.out.print(a);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    f(2, 5); //2,3,4,5,4,3,2
    System.out.println();
    f(5, 2); //5,4,3,2,3,4,5
}
```

There were a few problems with your code:

- If *a* is greater than *b*, the code would continue to execute until you get a StackOverflowError.
- When *a* and *b* are not equal, you're returning an integer, rather than a string.
- Printing *a + f(a + 1, b) + a* will cause the wrong output to be printed because you're calling a print function inside of a print function.